# Breaking down phone number in array using regular expression and php

Tags: php, regex

```
+91 9231665828  +91 9231665828
+91-9231675067  +91-9231675067
+919231665794   +919231665794
91 9231675653   91 9231675653
91-9231675067   91-9231675067
919231665794    919231665794
0 9231675653    0 9231675653
0-9231665808    0-9231665808
09231665808     09231665808
```

I have this kind of phone number set I want to break down those number in an array Like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => +91 9231665828
    [1] => +91-9231675067
    [2] => +919231665794
    [3] => 91 9231675653
    [4] => 91-9231675067
    [5] => 919231665794
    [6] => 0 9231675653
    [7] => 0-9231665808
    [8] => 09231665808
    [9] => +91 9231665828
    [10] => +91-9231675067
    [11] => +919231665794
    [12] => 91 9231675653
    [13] => 91-9231675067
    [14] => 919231665794
    [15] => 0 9231675653
    [16] => 0-9231665808
    [17] => 09231665808
)
```

I write some regular expression but not working.

`/\n|\s(?=(\+91(?:-|\s|)|91(?:-|\s|)|0(?:-|\s|))?[7-9][0-9]{9}$)/`

I want correct regular expression.

Comment: Why do you have the numbers twice in each row? If they are always the same you could read the whole line into a string and then only look at the first half of that string. Something along the lines of `firstHalf = wholeLine.substring(0, firstHalf.length / 2)` (sry for java-like pseudocode)

Comment: It can not same all time can be multiple column of numbers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not be more general and keep it simple?

```
\+?\d+[ -]?\d+
```

This matches all of your sample "phone numbers" and will break the string into an array. However, if you want to *validate* the numbers that's a different RegEx.

---

Example/test:

```
<?php

$string = "+91 9231665828 +91 9231665828
+91-9231675067  +91-9231675067
+919231665794   +919231665794
91 9231675653   91 9231675653
91-9231675067   91-9231675067
919231665794    919231665794
0 9231675653    0 9231675653
0-9231665808    0-9231665808
09231665808  09231665808";

if(preg_match_all('/\+?\d+[ -]?\d+/', $string, $matches))
{
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($matches[0]);
    echo '</pre>';
}

?>
```

results in:

```
Array
(
    [0] => +91 9231665828
    [1] => +91 9231665828
    [2] => +91-9231675067
    [3] => +91-9231675067
    [4] => +919231665794
    [5] => +919231665794
    [6] => 91 9231675653
    [7] => 91 9231675653
    [8] => 91-9231675067
    [9] => 91-9231675067
    [10] => 919231665794
    [11] => 919231665794
    [12] => 0 9231675653
    [13] => 0 9231675653
    [14] => 0-9231665808
    [15] => 0-9231665808
    [16] => 09231665808
    [17] => 09231665808
)
```

Comment: Yes it find the numbers. Thanks for that but when try to split in it gave remaining spaces.

Comment: Don't `preg_split`. Just use `preg_match_all` into a `$matches` array.

Answer (score 1):

use this pattern `^(\+?\d+[ -]?\d+)` notice the anchor `^`
[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/tK3nP9)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with **tenub** that validation is a separate task here. But you do need to make sure the engine knows where one number ends and another begins:

```
\+?\b\d{1,2}[ -]?\d{9,10}\b
```

Edit: I don't know the significance of the duplicate numbers, but if you only want the first one from each line you can throw a `^` at the beginning of the pattern:

```
^\+?\b\d{1,2}[ -]?\d{9,10}\b
```

Comment: I need all numbers. Not only the first one.

Comment: @AvikarshaSaha - Then this should work for you. If you're only getting one number back, use the `g` flag.